# Since when SE allow such accusations?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, policy

The comment

[image]

The mods response?

[image]

Comment: Hi @inactive
I declined the flags and I did it since I believe that everybody should be able to state his/her opinion here on this side, as long as others are not insulted. I couldn't see any insult in this comment. But I'm open to other opinions.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException if I go around posting the same comment you ok with that?

Comment: Sure, same rights for everyone.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I'll post this comment under every single question iHaveacomputer ever asked on every SE sites he is a member of, stay tuned

Comment: @inactive That's hardly a constructive behaviour on your part.

Comment: @inactive I'm sorry if you don't immediately see the difference.

Comment: @JoErNanO don't worry, the last thing I would do is to harm SE, I owe this network/community a lot, it's just that I am sick of those who whine like £*%#<, I have a thick skin and that's why I can't see when they get pain down there when I post a question they have no answer to

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I don't see the difference but I am bigger than him and his pathetic accusations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who made the comment turned out to be totally wrong.

The OP/myself was allowed at Luton airport and Glasgow airport. I haven't been told that I am not allowed, nor was I flagged by the CIA.

Also the police at the airport only asked me about my destination and once I said Glasgow the officer told me that I am ok, it was literally 4-5 seconds conversation and nobody mentioned SE travel.

Comment: You brought a Geiger counter on the flight? How did it go?

Answer (score 10):

Personally I do find that comment offensive. Not the part circled in red, but the "stupid shit" and "pay attention to me" parts cross a line for me. I am not even completely sure about the "obviously trolling" - while I have come to doubt (despite protestations to the contrary) that OP has a genuine intent to learn the things that are asked about, it's one thing to say "I have come to the conclusion the person is trolling" and another to say "this is obviously trolling". I probably wouldn't delete the comment for just that. But add in the word stupid and a little armchair diagnosis and it's too far for me.

And offensive or not, it sure isn't constructive. Let's say the comment is utterly and provably correct. How does it help me to deal with this question if I know that the CIA, TSA etc are tracking this bullet-proof-vest-wearing, gold-bar-carrying, rude-tshirt-wearing, ice-cream-vendor-abuser? It doesn't. Even if the comment stopped at "trolling" it's not really useful. Replace the insults with a call to action (like asking people not to answer, or to help you close) and there's a reason for declaring it to be trolling. Without them, it's just venting.

Comment: Totally agree with this. Antagonistic comments should be removed, it's not hard to remain civil on a site like this.